# Declare self in another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop

```
public class CustomSelectFields: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    let cities = ["city1", "city2"]
    let selectiveTextField = UITextField()
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()


    //normally it will get array of cities and frame position

    public func CreateCustomSelectField() -> UITextField {

        selectiveTextField.frame = CGRect(x: ScreenSize.width * 0.1, y: ScreenSize.height * 0.4, width: ScreenSize.width * 0.8, height: ScreenSize.height * 0.1)
        selectiveTextField.placeholder = "Placehoder"
        selectiveTextField.inputView = pickerView

        //should i declare delegates and datasoruce here?
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        return selectiveTextField
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return cities.count
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return cities[row]
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectiveTextField.text = cities[row]
        selectiveTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

I'm trying to create a custom UIPickerView and i want it to use in another classes. When I declare it's delegate and datasource in the same class, data are not showing up.

Also I try to declare in the class which is i use for viewController Like this:

```
let textField = customElements.CreateCustomSelectField()
customElements.pickerView.delegate = ??
customElements.pickerView.dataSource = ??

self.view.addSubview(textField)
```

How can I accomplish this delegate & datasource issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your design and your code are garbled. You've defined a class, `CustomSelectFields`, that looks like you want it to manage a text field and a picker view. Then you have a method, `CreateCustomSelectField`, that sounds like a convenience initializer for your `CustomSelectFields` class. However, it's actually an instance method that configures and returns a `UITextField` that belongs to the `CustomSelectFields` class.

Your `CustomSelectFields` class conforms to the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and  `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols, which suggests that you intend it to act as the delegate for the picker view. If that's the case, the `CustomSelectFields` class should have an initializer that creates the picker view and text field and configures them initially.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomSelectFields: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

  let cities = ["city1", "city2"]
  let selectiveTextField: UITextField
  let pickerView: UIPickerView

  init() {
    selectiveTextField = UITextField()
    selectiveTextField.frame = CGRect(x: ScreenSize.width * 0.1, 
      y: ScreenSize.height * 0.4, 
      width: ScreenSize.width * 0.8, 
      height: ScreenSize.height * 0.1)
    selectiveTextField.placeholder = "Placehoder" //Hodor! HODOR!
    selectiveTextField.inputView = pickerView

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
  }
}
```

But even still, having a class that creates and configures view objects - but doesn't display or manage them - is kind of odd.